# Why I can't debug jdk classes in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, classloader

I want to debug the Java Classloading process in Netbeans IDE, but I could not have success.

Do I need compile jdk classes to get debug info?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which classes you're talking about, but many of the JRE classes are implemented in native code, which a Java debugger can't debug.